# Trying to send email in PHP

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

I am trying to send an email with PHP in contact form but it's not working and also my code is working fine and there is no error in it. and I am not receiving any email. I am using PHPMailer and SMTP. What am I doing wrong? can please anyone tell me??
thanks in advance.
here is my code.

```
<?php
    $msg = "";
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    include_once "PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php";
    include_once "PHPMailer/Exception.php";
    include_once "PHPMailer/SMTP.php";

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $subject = $_POST['subject'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];

        $mail = new PHPMailer();

        //if we want to send via SMTP
        $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        //$mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->Username = "abc@gmail.com";
        $mail->Password = "mypassword";
        $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl"; //TLS
        $mail->Port = 465; //587

        $mail->addAddress('ammarkashmiri@gmail.com');
        $mail->setFrom($email);
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->isHTML(true);
        $mail->Body = $message;

        if ($mail->send())
            $msg = "Your email has been sent, thank you!";
        else
            $msg = "Please try again!";
    }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Contact Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" style="margin-top: 100px">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" align="center">
                <img src="images/logo.png"><br><br>

                <?php if ($msg != "") echo "$msg<br><br>"; ?>

                <form method="post" action="sendemail.php">
                    <input class="form-control" name="subject" placeholder="Subject..."><br>
                    <input class="form-control" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email..."><br>
                    <textarea placeholder="Message..." class="form-control" name="message"></textarea><br>
                    <input class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send Email">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use port 587 to send the mail https://www.mailgun.com/blog/25-465-587-what-port-should-i-use

Comment: still not woking :(

Comment: If $mail->send() returns true make sure the recipient email is right and check in the spam box.

Comment: @asyntsI already tried but nothing happened.

Comment: @FrancescoSimeoli i also checked in spam folder but also nothing is there and recipient is fine.

Comment: You commented out `isSMTP`, so none of your SMTP settings (including `Port`) are being used. You need to look in your local mail server's log files.